# Hello everyone I would like to make a radio button and make it select by pressing Enter key in React

Tags: reactjs

##### I Am failing to get the radio button selected when I press the `Enter` key

###### I tried this code here :

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

const HandleKeypress = () =\> {

    const [itWorks, setItWorks] = useState(true)
    
    useEffect(() => {
        document.addEventListener('keypress', (e) => {
            if (e.code === 'Enter') setItWorks(!itWorks)
            e.preventDefault();
        })
    }, [])
    
    return (
        <div>
            <p>{itWorks ? 'It works!' : 'It does not'}</p>
            <button onClick={() => setItWorks(!itWorks)} >Press me</button>
    
            <input type='radio' aria-selected onKeyPress={() => this.HandleKeypress } />
            
        </div>
    )

}

export default HandleKeypress;
```

Comment: Please read [ask] and take a [tour] before posting a question, and also what is [mre] and why it is important to provide it. Also, keep in mind that SO is not a forum but a Q&A site, we need to keep some qulaity

Answer (score 0):

1. You dont have to use onKeyPress() use onClick() instead.
2. You are using functional component, so, do

   ```
    <input type='radio' aria-selected onClick={handleClick} />
   ```
3. You cant call the main component which you are working on.
   So, the solution for this is

   ```
    import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

    const HandleKeypress = () => {

    const [itWorks, setItWorks] = useState(false)

    function handleClick(){
       SetItWorks(true)
    }

    return (
       <div>
         <p>{itWorks ? 'It works!' : 'It does not'}</p>
         <button onClick={() => 
    setItWorks(!itWorks)} >Press me</button>

         <input type='radio' aria-selected onClick={handleClick} />

       </div>
     )
   }

   export default HandleKeypress;
   ```

This will work.

Comment: Yash-sharma thanks for help but when I press enter to select radio btn still fails

Comment: Some additional help on that

Comment: if (e.code === 'Enter'.  how I select radio btn ?

Comment: Please do not answer to questions that lack  clarity or [mre]

Comment: Joseph Kagimu  -  This is because i didn't add the label in button tag for the radio button. When you do that it works properly. I just showed you here how ghis works in two ways by calling function or inside the statement. Rest you have to do by yourself.